# Eigen Tensor library - strided convolution

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I was wondering, is there a way to efficiently 'emulate' strided convolution in Eigen Tensor library, or any other in that sense ? It only provides convolution with fixed stride 1. Padding is pretty easy, it's just padding the input Tensor, but the stride is really inefficient, because the stride operation has to be applied at the end, which means that all values are computed, but half (or more) is then discarded. So far I have something like this (idx, shp2 and dim1<> are just aliases for Eigen indexing, all Tensors are rank 3, the filter 'b' is just flattened Tensor of rank 4):

```
inline void conv1(Tensor& c, const Tensor& a, const Tensor& b, shp2 st, shp2 pa) {
    c.data.setZero();
    idx nch = b.dimension(0) / a.dimension(0);
    dim1<2> str{st[0], st[1]};
    dim2<2> pad{ shp2{ pa[0], pa[0]}, shp2{ pa[1], pa[1] }};
    for(idx i = 0; i < nch; i++) {
        for(idx j = 0; j < a.dimension(0); j++) {
            c.chip(i, 0) += a.chip(j, 0).pad(pad).convolve(b.chip(i * a.dimension(0) + j, 0), dim1<2>{0, 1}).stride(str);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried doing the convolution completely by hand (minding column major memory layout), and the result is that for stride 2 and higher, it performs much better, but for stride 1 it performs much worse than the algorithm above, which leads me to think that I'm missing some optimization tricks from native implementation... the biggest bottleneck seems to be zeroing out the output 'c', even if I do it before the convolution, compiler seems to intertwine it into the nested loops and completely ruin the performance:

```
inline void conv2(Tensor& c, const Tensor& a, const Tensor& b, shp2 st, shp2 pa) {
    idx nch = b.dimension(0) / a.dimension(0);
    for(idx i = -pa[1], o = 0; i < (a.dimension(2) + pa[1] - b.dimension(2) + 1); i += st[1], o++) {
        for(idx j = -pa[0], p = 0; j < (a.dimension(1) + pa[0] - b.dimension(1) + 1); j += st[0], p++) {
            for(idx k = 0; k < nch; k++) {
                c(k, p, o) = 0;
                for(idx l = 0; l < b.dimension(2); l++) {
                    for(idx m = 0; m < b.dimension(1); m++) {
                        if(size_t(i + l) < a.dimension(2) && size_t(j + m) < a.dimension(1)) {
                            for(idx n = 0; n < a.dimension(0); n++) {
                                c(k, p, o) += a(n, j + m, i + l) * b(k * a.dimension(0) + n, m, l);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried doing the convolution by slicing, but that performs even worse than both algorithms...

In summary I want to either know if there is a way to efficiently stride in the first algorithm, or to fix the second one.

Thank you.

Update:
The second algorithm works infact perfectly... Just not in Clang15...
https://godbolt.org/z/bMGbvTGTT